# Dagger 2 injecting parameters

Tags: android, dependency-injection, dagger-2, dagger

I want to get a instance of file, `fileOutputStream` , `fileIntputStream` using di pattern so i created a module and provides for all the three dependencies but since file object requires a path i passed it as a `param`.

```
@Provides
File provideFile(String filePath){
    return new File(filePath);
}

@Provides
FileOutputStream provideFileOutputStream(String filePath){
    return new FileIntputStream(provideFile(filePath));
}

@Provides
FileIntputStream provideFileIntputStream(String filePath){
    return new FileIntputStream(provideFile(filePath));
}
```

And then i got this following error :

```
"@inject constructor or from an @provides-annotated method. java.lang.string is injected"
```

Upon some research i came across concept of "Newables", "Injectables" and since string is a newable i.e. its doesn't have a fixed implementation and we need to call it manually and there a lot if it hence di cannot infer which object to use, so my question is can di be used to only create object whose `params` are known at compile time, and if so what the point of it just to create object that have static/fixed parameters.

Answer (score 3):

You kind of have the idea of DI a bit wrong.  DI doesn't take parameters, especially not Dagger-  its a compile time implementation.  The only legal parameters to a DI provider are other injected variables.  There's absolutely 0 point in injecting a File if you have to provide the path anyway-  just call new at that point.

Where you would use injection is if you wanted to get a specific file-  lets say the file for your main db.  Then you would have:

```
@Provides
File provideFile(){
    return new File("/my/path);
}
```

As for what's the point of DI-  there's a couple.  One is its used to scope variables.  Another is to make testing easier-  by injecting variables rather than accessing singletons you can easily put in partial implementations, mocks, or pure test implementations.  It also makes it easy to switch out implementations of abstract interfaces including entire subsystems-  just switch what subcomponents you add.

(BTW if you want you can inject a string path, I do it in a few places in my current app.  But you have to use @Named so you can tell which string to inject.  That's true anytime you want to inject more than 1 instance of some type).

Comment: Sorry for question i just started learning about Di , so only params allowed are those that can be injected i.e. they are set during compile time eg : Injecting okHttpClient in retrofit builder, and also i looked up a few places but couldn't understand how @Named works could you please elaborate a little

Comment: If you want to provide 2 of the same type, you annotate the provider with @ Provides and @ Named("name").  Then when you inject it, you inject it with @ Named("name"), so it knows which one to inject.  For example @ Provides @ Named("baseUri") public void String providesBaseUri() { return "http://example.com/";}

Answer (score 1):

```
@Provides
File provideFile(String filePath){
   return new File(filePath);
}
```

Error lies here. This function looks for String parameter which is not given by Provides method so you can change it to

```
@Provides
FileOutputStream provideFileOutputStream(File file) {
    return new FileOutputStream(file);
}

@Provides
FileIntputStream provideFileIntputStream(File file) {
     return new FileIntputStream(file);
}
```

Another way to solve is using Qualifiers or Named. Since you've figured out Named I am giving you a sample of Qaulifiers.

```
@Provides
@OutputQualifier
String provideOutFile(){
   return outFilePath;
}


@Provides
@InputQualifier
String provideInFile(){
   return inputFilePath;
}


@Provides
FileOutputStream provideFileOutputStream(@OutputQualifier String file) {
    return new FileOutputStream(new File(file));
}

@Provides
FileIntputStream provideFileIntputStream(@InputQualifier String file) {
     return new FileIntputStream(new File(file));
}
```

Qualifiers defination:

```
@Qualifier
public @interface InputQualifier {
}


@Qualifier
public @interface OutputQualifier {
}
```

Go over this video for more learnings on Qualifiers https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=WAENNp2wxbQ

Happy Coding :)